# RLE algorithm should compress bytes in c

Tags: c

I know there are too many questions about this algorithm but I couldn't really find a good answer for compressing the bytes. I am kind of a newbie in C. I have the following code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

//compress function here...

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    if(argc != 2){
        fprintf(stderr, "Wrong argument number\n");
        exit(1);
    } 

    FILE *source = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    if(source == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open the file to be read\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    FILE *destination;
    char name = printf("%s.rle", argv[1]);
    while((destination = fopen(&name, "wb")) == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't create the file to be written\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    compress_file(source, destination);

    int error;
    error = fclose(source);
    if(error != 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: fclose failed for source file\n");
    }
    error = fclose(destination);
    if(error != 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: fclose failed for destination file\n");
    }
}
```

If this is test.c and the executable is test. I need to make this work on terminal/command prompt as "./test file.txt". My file.txt includes something like (bytes):

20 21 20 20 8F 8F 21 21 64 60 70 20 21 90 90

and the desired output is:

01 20 01 21 02 20 02 8F 02 21 01 64 01 60 01 70 01 20 01 21 02 90

My code create a file and that file includes:

0b00 0000 0106 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0a

instead what I want. What do I miss?

Also I want my file to be named as file.txt.rle but it has no name.

EDIT:

```
char name[30];
sprintf(name, "%s.rle", argv[1]);
```

solved the problem for naming.

Comment: `char name = printf("%s.rle", argv[1]);` is not the way to make a string with a file name. Look up `sprintf`

Comment: `char str[BUF_SIZE];
fwrite(str, sizeof(str), 1, destination);` This just write an uninitialized variable (i.e. `str`) to the file. You need to put something into `str` first

Comment: @4386427 solved the problem with the name thank you!!

What should I put in str though? I don't want anything else but my output in the file. Is it the only problem?

Comment: Inside the while loop, you need to put the encoded values into `str`

Comment: @4386427 I am trying to get it from the file.txt. That's what I tried to do with fgetc, isn't it the right way? I am a newbie :)

Comment: Look at repeat_count. You initialize it, you count it, but you never use it...

Comment: turn on all warnings and solve those first

Comment: @Holger that's absolutely right! instead fwrite can I just use `putc(repeat_count, destination); putc(previous_character, destination);` ?

@phuclv Sorry, I didn't get what you mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Also I want my file to be named as file.txt.rle but it has no name.

Well, this code

```
char name = printf("%s.rle", argv[1]);
while((destination = fopen(&name, "wb")) == NULL){
```

doesn't give you a string like "file.txt.rle". Instead try something like:

```
size_t len = strlen(argv[1]) + 4 + 1;
char name[len];
sprintf(name, "%s.rle", argv[1]);
while((destination = fopen(name, "wb")) == NULL){
```

> instead what I want. What do I miss?

Well, you miss that you need to put data into `str`

This code

```
char str[BUF_SIZE];
fwrite(str, sizeof(str), 1, destination);
```

just writes an uninitialized variable to the file.

I'll not give you a complete solution but here is something that you can start with and then figure the rest out yourself.

```
void compress_file(FILE *source, FILE *destination){

    char str[BUF_SIZE];
    int index = 0;

    int repeat_count = 0;
    int previous_character = EOF;
    int current_character;

    while((current_character = fgetc(source)) != EOF){
        if(current_character != previous_character) {

            if (previous_character != EOF) {
                // Save the values to str
                str[index++] = repeat_count;
                str[index++] = previous_character;
            }

            previous_character = current_character;
            repeat_count = 1;
        }
        else{
            repeat_count++;
        }
    }
    if (repeat_count != 0)
    {
        str[index++] = repeat_count;
        str[index++] = previous_character;
    }

    fwrite(str, index, 1, destination);
}
```

EXAMPLE 1:

Let's say a file.txt is:

```
ABBCCC
```

On linux it can be displayed hexadecimal like this:

```
# hexdump -C file.txt
00000000  41 42 42 43 43 43                                 |ABBCCC|
```

After running the program, you have:

```
hexdump -C file.txt.rle
00000000  01 41 02 42 03 43                                 |.A.B.C|
```

EXAMPLE 2:

Let's say that file.txt is like

```
# hexdump -C file.txt
00000000  20 21 20 20 8f 8f 21 21  64 60 70 20 21 90 90     | !  ..!!d`p !..|
```

the result will be

```
# hexdump -C file.txt.rle
00000000  01 20 01 21 02 20 02 8f  02 21 01 64 01 60 01 70  |. .!. ...!.d.`.p|
00000010  01 20 01 21 02 90                                 |. .!..|
```

Comment: I used sprintf for the name and it solved my problem :)

This code gives me a weird output something like:
<0x01>2<0x01>0<0x01>...

I just got the same output using putc, I don't even know why I got this

Comment: @C.J Are you sure that your txt file doesn't contain '2' '0' instead of the hex value 20 ?

Comment: The txt file example is shown in hexadecimal but then why the expected is  01 20 01 21 02 20 02 8F 02 21 01 64 01 60 01 70 01 20 01 21 02 90 ? :/

it does the right thing then?

Comment: I mean they are bytes

Comment: I'll suggest that you start with a more simple txt file. Try a file containing: ABBCCC  In bytes (decimal) that is 65 66 66 67 67 67 That should give the result  01 65 02 66 03 67

Comment: When I decompress the output of my file though I get 20 21 20 20 8F 8F 21 21 64 60 70 20 21 90 90

so that's why I am confused. It seems like doesn't give me what I want when I compress it but when I decompress it, it does give the right result

Comment: I got `0x01>6<0x01>5<0x01>...` with your example. it eliminated one of the 66 but didn't do anything to 67 but in the format I typed

Comment: @C.J I think there is something wrong with either your input file or the way you look at the result file. With the txt file containing `ABBCCC` which as hexadecimal bytes are `41 42 42 43 43 43` I get the result `01 41 02 42 03 43` just as expected. I think your input file is "65 ..." **as text**

Comment: are you putting in the txt the numbers or the characters ?

Comment: @C.J The characters... simply type from keyboard: ABBCCC

Comment: I was putting the numbers but I can’t see bytes then like in either case I can’t get the numbers you get, can you tell me what I should exactly put in the file.txt and when I run the code as ./test file.txt what file.txt.rle has to have

Comment: @C.J You need a program that can show files in hexadecimal view. Some editors (e.g. emacs) can which between "character view" and "hexadecimal view". On linux there are programs like `hexdump` - it can be used like `hexdump -C file.txt.rle`

Comment: got this when I put ABBCCC  01 41 02 42 03 43                                 |.A.B.C| thanks a lot!

Comment: getting that exactly, thank you! I was completely blacked out about using hexdump

Comment: can you use my example like the one in the question?

Comment: @C.J Updated with one more example and changed the code a bit

Comment: `00000000  32 30 20 32 31 20 32 30  20 32 30 20 38 66 20 38  |20 21 20 20 8f 8|
 00000010  66 20 32 31 20 32 31 20  36 34 20 36 30 20 37 30  |f 21 21 64 60 70|
 00000020  20 32 30 20 32 31 20 39  30 20 39 30              | 20 21 90 90|
 0000002c`

problem is here:
`#hexdump -C file.txt`

Comment: `00000000  01 32 01 30 01 20 01 32  01 31 01 20 01 32 01 30  |.2.0. .2.1. .2.0|
00000010  01 20 01 32 01 30 01 20  01 38 01 66 01 20 01 38  |. .2.0. .8.f. .8|
00000020  01 66 01 20 01 32 01 31  01 20 01 32 01 31 01 20  |.f. .2.1. .2.1. |
00000030  01 36 01 34 01 20 01 36  01 30 01 20 01 37 01 30  |.6.4. .6.0. .7.0|
00000040  01 20 01 32 01 30 01 20  01 32 01 31 01 20 01 39  |. .2.0. .2.1. .9|
00000050  01 30 01 20 01 39 01 30                           |.0. .9.0|
00000058`

and this is the result of `#hexdump -C file.txt.rle`

Answer (score 1):

As pointed in comments, you have two problems:

- Usage of `printf` instead of `sprintf`,
- Writting to file what you've counted.

## Name Creation

```
char name = printf("%s.rle", argv[1]);
destination = fopen(&name, "wb");
```

The first line will store the number of characters in `argv[1]` plus 4 into `name`. Since, from [`man printf`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf):

> Upon successful return, these functions return the number of characters printed (excluding the null byte used to end output to strings).

The second line is more problematic : you ask `fopen` to open a file giving it a pointer to char instead of a read string.

One correct way to do what you want is:

```
/* reserve memory to store file name
   NOTE: 256 here might not large enough*/
char name[256];
/* fill name array with original name + '.rle' 
   The return of sprintf is tested to assert that its size was enough */    
if (snprintf(name, sizeof name, "%s.rle", argv[1]) >= sizeof name)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "name variable is not big enough to store destination filename");
}
```

## Writting to file

The code

```
char str[BUF_SIZE];
fwrite(str, sizeof(str), 1, destination);
```

reserve a big array, and writes it to file, without initializing it. To do what you want, you can have this approach:

- make a function that will only write two characters in file: the number of character found and the character itself
- call this function each time needed (at character changing, but not when one of character is EOF...)

Let's look at :

```
void write_char_to_file(FILE *f, int count, char car)
{
    /* char array to be stored in file */
    char str[2];   
    /* number of repeating characters */
    str[0] = count;
    /* the character */
    str[1] = car;
    /* write it to file */
    fwrite(str, sizeof str, 1, f);    
}
```

This function has two potential problems:

- It doesn't handle `char` overflow (what if `count` is over 256?),
- It doesn't test the return of `fwrite`.

Then, when this function should be called, when the current character changes:

```
EOF A A B C C EOF
```

In this example, we have 4 characters changes, but we want only 3 writting in the file, so:

- Character changing when previous is EOF must be ignored (else we would write something like `0 (char)EOF` at file starting),
- One writting must be added after `while` loop since, when the last reading gives `EOF`, we still have `2 C` to write to file.

Let's look at the code:

```
while((current_character = fgetc(source)) != EOF) {
    if(current_character != previous_character) { 
        /* ignore initial change */            
        if (previous_character != EOF) {  
            write_char_to_file(destination, repeat_count, previous_character);
        }
        previous_character = current_character;
        repeat_count = 1;
    } else {
        repeat_count++;
    }
}
/* write last change */
write_char_to_file(destination, repeat_count, previous_character);
```

This code have a problem too: what if the input file is empty? (first read gives `EOF`)

---

The complete code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 5096

void write_char_to_file(FILE *f, int count, char car)
{
    /* char array to be stored in file */
    char str[2];   
    /* number of repeating characters */
    str[0] = count;
    /* the character */
    str[1] = car;
    /* write it to file */
    fwrite(str, sizeof str, 1, f);    
}

void compress_file(FILE *source, FILE *destination)
{
    int repeat_count = 0;
    int previous_character = EOF;
    int current_character;

    while((current_character = fgetc(source)) != EOF) {
        if(current_character != previous_character) {            
            if (previous_character != EOF) {  
                write_char_to_file(destination, repeat_count, previous_character);
            }
            previous_character = current_character;
            repeat_count = 1;
        } else {
            repeat_count++;
        }
    }
    write_char_to_file(destination, repeat_count, previous_character);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if(argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Wrong argument number\n");
        exit(1);
    } 

    FILE *source = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    if(source == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open the file to be read\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    FILE *destination;
    /* reserve memory to store file name
       NOTE: 256 here might not large enough*/
    char name[256];
    /* fill name array with original name + '.rle' 
       The return of sprintf is tested to assert that its size was enough */    
    if (snprintf(name, sizeof name, "%s.rle", argv[1]) >= sizeof name)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "name variable is not big enough to store destination filename");
    }
    
    /* while is not needed here, if do the job */
    if((destination = fopen(name, "wb")) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't create the file to be written\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    compress_file(source, destination);
    
    int error;
    error = fclose(source);
    if(error != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: fclose failed for source file\n");
    }
    error = fclose(destination);
    if(error != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: fclose failed for destination file\n");
    }
    
    /* main must return a integer */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation I understood a lot more! There is only one problem I still can't get the result I want, I am getting something like:
`0x01>2<0x01>0<0x01> <0x01>2<0x01>1<0x01> ... <0x01>9<0x01>0<0x02>` and when I drag this output file to atom or sublime it gives me my input file is it what it is supposed to do? Because I am trying to get something like:
01 20 01 21 02 20 02 8F 02 21 01 64 01 60 01 70 01 20 01 21 02 90

Sorry if this is a stupid question

Comment: @C.J Well, Can you update your question to precise exactly what is the input format (I though that the `20 20 21`... was the hexudecimal code of characters) and What output you expect (text/binary numbers, characters or characters code...)